# NSComboBoxCell on the list, always changing all rows

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have list of employees, created as NSTableView, with two columns. First is employee name, second is employee role, which should be selected from combo box.
I added to this column NSComboBoxCell, and I set column bindings to:

```
Content - RolesController.arrangedObjects
Content Values - RolesController.arrangedObjects.roleName
Value - EmployeesController.selection.role.roleName

RolesController is NSArrayController based on Role entity
EmployeesController is NSArrayController based on Employee entity.
```

This works almost correctly, shows roles, allows to choose role, but when I choose role in one row (for one employee), role changes in all rows (for all employees).
I have been looking for solution, but in all founded examples bindings are exactly as in my case.

Does anyone know where I've made mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so stupid. I should connect:

```
Value -> EmployeesController.arrangedObjects.role.roleName
```

Now, everything works correctly.